# Custom Command as LinkButton instead of Button in Telerik Grid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I have Telerik Grid in my cshtml and it has two custom column commands in a Telerik Grid. Now Custom Commands are rendered as Buttons and i want them to be displayed as Links instead of Buttons.. Is it possible? How to achieve it?

The Custom Column Commands code is as follows

```
    columns.Command(commands => commands
        .Custom("Edit")
        .Text("Edit")
        .SendState(false)
        .DataRouteValues(route =>

     {

route.Add(o => o.SuppliersInvoiceNumber).RouteKey("InvoiceNumber");

    })

    .Ajax(true));


    columns.Command(commands => commands

    .Custom("remove")

    .Text("Delete")

    .SendState(false)

    .DataRouteValues(route =>

     {

route.Add(o => o.PONumber).RouteKey("PONumber");

     })

     .Ajax(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Commands "buttons" are links under the hood. Just overwrite css applyed by the theme and you will get a real link.

```
.t-button {
   border: 0 none transparent;
   min-width: 0;
   border-radius: 0; 
   margin: 0;
   background:none;
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

Maybe you will have to add additional properties to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HtmlAttributes` of the Command button to style the buttons. In fact, setting the `background:none` would expose that the button is indeed a hyperlink.